# Manual jack up of Maxwell-Boltzmann scale parameter?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, temperature

I first noticed this phenomenon when i was a child, about 4 decades ago.  I needed a piece of wire but could not find a pair of pliers with which to cut the wire.  So i used a technique i once saw my father use.  I made a sharp bend on the wire (i think it was galvanised iron wire) at the point where i needed the cut.  Then i undid the bend by bending in the opposite direction and proceeded further so that the wire was bent again but in the opposite direction.  I repeated the process, bending the wire back and forth until metal fatigue weakened the microstructure of the wire until the piece i needed came off from the main roll of wire.  Since i used my bare hands in the process, i noticed that the wire got hot after several bendings.  It got so hot i had to stop to let the wire cool a bit first before proceeding again.

As an adult, i occasionally found myself in similar wire-but-no-cutting-pliers-around situations, and each time it makes me wonder, is it due to a mere increase in the scale parameter of the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution of the speeds of the metal atoms?  I suspect that the conduction band plays a role in this phenomenon; so what is the role of the conduction band, noting that the system constitutes an open circuit, because the ends of the wire are not connected to form a closed loop/circuit (i.e., a closed circuit with an emf source)?  Is there a formula that can be used to determine the relative contributions of the constituent particles (electrons compared with metal atoms) to the overall rise in the temperature?

The radius of the bend is about 0.5 cm or 0.25 inch wide, and at 1 bend per second, the speed of motion/bending at the bend cannot exceed 2 cm•s<sup>-1</sup>.  And yet, it exerts an influence which is enough to significantly increase the kinetic energies of the particles involved, with the iron atoms initially possessing vibrational speeds of ca 200 m•s<sup>-1</sup>.  Are there possible quantum effects?  What could really be going on here?

The same thing happens when dealing with metal sheets.

Answer (score 2):

The temperature increase happens because you are plastically deforming the metal.

When you apply a force to the metal to bend it you are doing work. In an elastic solid that work would be stored as elastic energy and you'd get the work back when you released the metal and it returned to its original shape. In this case the temperature of the metal would be unchanged.

In plastic deformation you do work to bend the metal, but because the metal stays bent instead of springing back you don't get that work back. Since energy is conserved the work you put in has to go somewhere, and in this case it is being converted to heat by viscous forces during the shearing of the metal. It's the energy you supply that is heating the metal.

The Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution applies only to ideal gases. In solids the atoms may be vibrating but they are not translating.

Comment: Thanks. I've had formal training in thermodynamics and i know about transformations/conservation of energy, forms of energy, etc. It is also true that atoms in a solid are just vibrating (&possibly rotating), not translating,and this is primarily the definition of what a solid is. What i'm wondering about is this:  motion of ca _**2 cm•s<sup>-1</sup>**_ affecting a system of particles moving at ca _**200 m•s<sup>-1</sup>**_ to the extent that it raises the temperature by at least _**30 K**_ (55°F). Which is primarily producing the effect? The iron atoms or the electrons in the conduction band?

Comment: BTW, i cited the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution only to provide a rough approximation / general idea of particle speed distribution.

Comment: @lomdemanil insulators get hot when deformed as well, even though they have empty conduction bands. The electrons in metals certainly play a role in the thermal properties, e.g. they are very important in determining thermal conductivity, but the thermal energy is largely in the vibrating atoms.

Comment: Yes, i thought so to, the thermal energy eventually gets transferred to the atoms, increasing their vibration.  To rephrase the question, does the input of 2 **cm** / s motion into the wire affect the speed of atoms moving at 200 **m** / s to the extent that the net effect is to significantly increase the temperature by 30 K?  Can we really rule out resistive heating due to motion of electrons in the conduction band as a significant source of the effect?